# Append HTMLElement to the middle of an inline element

Tags: javascript

FYI: It is desirable that solutions be strictly vanilla Javascript.

How can I append an HTMLElement object to the middle of an element?
Here's a sample with a bit of what I mean.

```js
const paragraph = document.createElement('p')
paragraph.innerHTML = 'Here is some text.<br><br>There is some text.'

document.body.appendChild(paragraph)

const wrappper = document.createElement('div')
const button = document.createElement('button')

button.onmouseup = () =>
{
    // Do something
}

wrapper.appendChild(button)
```

Now imagine for a moment that I want to put the `wrapper` element inside of the `paragraph` element. But, not at the beginning or the end of it, but rather somewhere in the middle such as between the `<br>` tags. (But not necessarily after a tag)  This can be done rather easily by taking the `outerHTML` of `wrapper` and inserting it into the `paragraph`'s `innerHTML` via substrings, but this presents a problem. The resulting elements now in the flow of the html page are not the same as `wrapper` or `button`, which is evident when logging them, or when there is no `onmouseup` event being triggered.

So, ultimately, how do I put the exact `HTMLElements` referenced by the defined variables into the flow of the document in the middle of the contents of another element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a temporary `<span>` with a known `id` and then replace it with the element you wish to [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) would do...

```js
const paragraph = document.createElement('p')
paragraph.innerHTML = 'Here is some text.<br><span id="destination"></span><br>There is some text.'

document.body.appendChild(paragraph)

const wrapper = document.createElement('div')
const button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerText = "here"

button.onmouseup = () =>
{
    // Do something
}

wrapper.appendChild(button)

let destination = document.querySelector("#destination")
destination.replaceWith(wrapper)
```

Comment: Inserting an empty element and replacing it with the desired element did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Find the `<br>` element and use [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) to insert after it.

```js
const paragraph = document.createElement('p')
paragraph.innerHTML = 'Here is some text.<br><br>There is some text.'

document.body.appendChild(paragraph)

const wrappper = document.createElement('div')
const button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerText = 'Click';
const br = paragraph.querySelector("br");

br.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', button);
```

Comment: The existence if the <br> tags was just an arbitrary part of the example, I wanted to be able to insert it anywhere and not strictly next to a tag, so I suppose it was a poor example on my part. Oh well, these answers ended up being helpful anyways.

Comment: If you want to insert into the middle of text, you would need to split it up into two text nodes so you can put an element between them. I suggest you come up with a design that doesn't require this.